# How to get list of translated languages in app using php gettext

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

How can I get a list of all languages (translations included with app) included with my project (not a system)?

files are stored in folders:

```
/lang/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/domain.po
/lang/it_IT.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/domain.po
```

I know I could perform a search on files, but I think there could be a better way of doing it. Manuals and forums are showing possible locales installed ( `locale -a` ) on a whole system, not a list of translations on the application.

What would be the best way of getting such list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to search the directories. The command `locale -a` lists locale definitions installed on your system and that has nothing to do with which translations your application installs.

And, by the way, you should install compiled `.mo` files, not the `.po` source files in these directories.